# Remove 2nd occurence after a given flag

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

How can I parse every line in a .txt file to remove everything after the second occurrence of a `/` after a given flag `jdk` on each line of a file.

For example

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-1.7.0/2.0/zi/etc/GMT
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.2/3.0/zi/etc/GMT
/usr/share/servertool-java-openjdk/4.0/jce.jar
```

becomes

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-1.7.0/2.0/
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.2/3.0/
/usr/share/servertool-java-openjdk/4.0/
```

Note, I can't just split on jdk, because it may be `jdk-1.*.*/ etc.`

My end goal is to find all the unique paths on a highly restricted SeLinux box that has the output of a locate jdk stored in a output.txt file

Update: my attempt so far, to get closer is

```
cat output.txt | awk -F '\\jdk' '{print $1"jdk"}' | sort -u
```

This just chops everything after jdk, and removes dupes.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is a very appropriate tool for this job. You'll use the `s///` command to remove the part of the line you want to delete.

Note the slashes in the `s///` command can be changed to other characters so that any slashes you have in the pattern or replacement parts don't need to be escaped.

Your pattern will be:

- in capturing parentheses:

  - "jdk" followed by zero or more non-slashes
  - followed by a slash
  - followed by one or more non-slashes
  - followed by a slash
- followed by any number of characters

The replacement will be the text that was captured.

You'll want to refer to the [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html)

- [3.3 The `s` Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)
- [5 Regular Expressions: selecting text](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-regular-expressions.html#sed-regular-expressions)
- [5.2 Basic (BRE) and extended (ERE) regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html#BRE-vs-ERE)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to replace in the same file, you can use below script

```
#!/bin/bash
cat output.txt | while read line
do
x=${line#/*jdk*/*/}
replace=${line%${x}}
sed -i "s|$line|$replace|g" output.txt
done
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to call out to sed: $replace contains the wanted new line, so just echo it. Particularly you don't want to `sed -i` inside a loop, that's very inefficient.

Comment: Also, to read the file exactly verbatim, you need to `while IFS= read -r line` -- that will preserve any backslashes in the data as well as leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: And "useless use of cat": `while ...; done < filename`